# Failed to launch javascript debug adapter in Visual Studio

Tags: javascript, visual-studio, debugging

[image]

I want to debug my script code in my visual studio but I see this error?
How can I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try disabling the Javascript debugging adapter for your browser in the options.

Also, make sure all your browser windows are closed when you go to run the project, and enable "Automatically close the console when debugging stops" in Options -> Debugging in VS.